# Is there any relevance to set theory and level of truthfulness when comparing the truth values across several logic systems?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, truth

Is there any relevance to set theory and level of truthfulness when comparing the truth values across several logic systems? Can't word it any better, so I will try to explain what I mean. So there are several logic systems, and there are some statements that are true in 5 different logic systems out of 10, and some are true in 10 out of 10, so is there any relevance or use in comparing the level of truthfulness of a statement across several logic systems, or there is no reason to ever do that since only 1 logic system is relevant at a time?

Comment: What do you mean by true? Isn't truth relative to the *model* of a particular logic system and not the logic system itself? And exactly what do you mean by a logic system in this context?

Comment: There is, although it is not really quantifiable. Logics serve such purposes as codifying our reasoning intuitions and technical devices useful in applications. If multiple logics affirm some principles while diverging on others chances are that such core principles are particularly apt and useful. However, the number of logics is not very indicative in this regard, one can generate infinite number of stillborn ones at will. Only those that proved to be productive in some field count, and those to varying degrees that can only be vaguely assessed.

Comment: Truth isn't relative to the logical system. Derivability/provability differs from one logical system to another, but that isn't truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let P be a statement. Then, we can find arbitrarily many logics where P is true: take P as an axiom, tonk operator, inconsistent logic, etc. So in some sense no.

But, also, there are statements that remain true across a wide variety of logical systems. Take the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, or any other "deep" result. It holds in many different logics, so we might say that our concept of the numbers is quite robust. Similarly with other statements. So in some sense, yes.

What accounts for this phenomena? Perhaps because we have chosen our foundational systems to make these statements true.

Comment: Bad example. Unique factorization fails quite often. See "non examples" here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain

Comment: This is for UFDs, not arithmetic simpliciter. Yes, if you generalize to arbitrary rings, which is quite a bit of additional structure on top of the typical set theoretic encoding of the naturals. But in any case, if you don't like it, there are many other such examples